# Arcobjects ConstructBuffers produces Error -2147220889?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, geometry, buffer

I use the Esri-function [ConstructBuffers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ConstructBuffers_Method/002m000000ns000000/) in my arcobjects program. The call of this method produces a Error with code -2147220889.

Looking up the error constants it says:

> FDO_E_WORKSPACE_INVALID_KEYSETID -2147220889 Returned Keyset id is
>   invalid.

what does that mean?

The geometriy list that I provide for the buffer creation is created by myself in my Software. I did some operations to make sure the geometries are correct like: Simplify, SnapToSpatialReference.
The buffer creation is executed in a loop and strangely it works with most geometry lists that I provide as input but only crashes with a few of them. I can not see why that is so. Who has an idea what could be the cause?

```
            IGeometryBag subcurvesBag = new GeometryBagClass();
            IGeometryCollection subcurvesCollection = (IGeometryCollection) subcurvesBag;
            GeometryBag buffersGeoBag = new GeometryBagClass();
            IGeometryCollection buffersGeoColl = (IGeometryCollection) buffersGeoBag;

            foreach (IPolyline subCurve in subCurveList)
            {
                if (subCurve.IsEmpty)
                {
                    subCurveList.Remove(subCurve);
                }
                subCurve.SpatialReference = map.SpatialReference;
                subCurve.PrepareForTopologicalOperation();//simplify
                subcurvesCollection.AddGeometry(subCurve);
            }

            IBufferConstructionProperties bufferConstProp = (IBufferConstructionProperties) bufferConstruction;
            bufferConstProp.EndOption = esriBufferConstructionEndEnum.esriBufferFlat;
            bufferConstruction.ConstructBuffers((IEnumGeometry) subcurvesCollection, bufferSize, buffersGeoColl);
```

Comment: Coding questions are expected to contain code.  Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where are the geometries stored? I found a KB article about keyset tables and IDs. At least at that point (2008) they were used in a geodatabase to traverse relationship classes.

Comment: Have you tried setting `IBufferConstructionProperties.GenerateCurves = false`?  Sometimes arcgis chokes on arcs.

Comment: mkennedy: the geometries are stored in an Oracle sde. However the buffer geometries are never written to a Feature or shapefile. I keep them in a  IGeometryCollection (buffersGeoColl) and only use them in another topological operation later. They are just used as intermediate result in my process.

Comment: I solved it: I added several buffer options (                bufferConstProp.GenerateCurves = false;
                bufferConstProp.ExplodeBuffers = false;
                bufferConstProp.UnionOverlappingBuffers = true;) and removed very small polylines from my calculation. Not sure which exactly did the trick but it runs smooth now. Could be that Kirk Kuykendall was right with the arc issue.

Answer (score 1):

-2147220889 is 80040267 in hexadecimal form.
Then I googled for 80040267 ArcObjects and found this:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000019000000

"(0x80040267) An error occurred during the buffer operation."